# Oneplus 8T stuck in bootloop after flashing patched boot.img

Tags: fastboot, boot-loop, unbricking, oneplus

I'm a complete newbie following a guide to root my phone, but it got stuck in a bootloop after rebooting, after flashing a patched boot.img created by Magisk. I have tried many things but with my lack of experience I'm stuck. One guide I'm following for unbricking your phone requires flashing all files from a stock (official) payload.bin file, but I can't run the commands because of a 'critical partition' error.

Running 'fastboot flashing unlock_critical' only prints out the syntax commands as if I just typed in 'fastboot' as is... I'm stuck, I'm clueless and I'm beginning to panic ._.

Comment: for patching, stock boot.img is required. furthermore unlocked bootloader is required for flashing magisk_patched.img from fastboot. because of this two requirements i see no constraint to unbrick your device by just reverting your modification. only flash stock boot.img